# How can I deal with closed ports in Scapy?

Tags: python, network-programming, scapy

I am trying to understand how **Scapy** works by sending TCP / IP packets to my local router on the ports 22, 53 and 80. The ports 53 and 80 are open - 22 is closed:

```
p = sr(IP(dst="192.168.1.1")/TCP(dport=[22, 53, 80]))

Begin emission:
.*Finished to send 3 packets.
.................................................
.................................................
.................................................
etc
.........................................^C
Received 24571 packets, got 2 answers, remaining 1 packets
```

If I just send packets to port 53 and 80 - no problems occur:

```
In [5]: p = sr(IP(dst="192.168.1.1")/TCP(dport=[53, 80]))
Begin emission:
.*Finished to send 2 packets.
*
Received 3 packets, got 2 answers, remaining 0 packets
```

**Scapy Version -> 2.3.1 (latest)**

- **How can I deal with closed ports in Scapy?**
- **Why I receive so many answers?**

---

**UPDATE**
Thanks to the @pss's comment here is the captured data of wireshark with the filter `host 192.168.1.1`:

```
In [28]: p = sr(IP(dst="192.168.1.1")/TCP(dport=[53, 80, 1111]))
Begin emission:
.**Finished to send 3 packets.
..........................................
..........................................
..........................................
etc
.........................^C
Received 313 packets, got 2 answers, remaining 1 packets
```

[image: wireshark capture]

Comment: Try wireshark to see the packets! :)

Comment: I added a wireshark capture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that ports 22 and 1111 are filtered: they may be closed or open on the system but something (a firewall) prevent us from getting an answer.

If you want `sr()` to terminate even when some packets have not received any answer, you can add a `timeout=` value (in seconds):

```
p = sr(IP(dst="192.168.1.1")/TCP(dport=[22, 53, 80]), timeout=2)
```

Comment: Do you know why I receive so many packets if the destination port does not exist? (-> `Received 24571 packets`)

Comment: These are the packets seen by Scapy that are **not** related to the packets Scapy has sent (they are not answers to be returned by `sr()`). There might be a lot of reason why you see an important amount of data (like, you have a download running in another process, or you see traffic from other stations on the network, etc.). Try to run `sniff(prn=lambda x: x.summary())` to know what packets are seen by Scapy.

Comment: yeah, that explained all these packets!